# Conversion from string "16/11/2013" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

i try  this script to view report using paramaters, but i always receive message 
"Conversion from string "16/11/2013" to type 'Date' is not valid".
on control panel customize regional option, i use this for short date format "M/d/yyyy",
please help, i really need to make this run

```
     Dim frRpt As New FrLaporan_Penjualan
        Dim per_tgl_awal, per_tgl_akhir As Date

        per_tgl_awal = Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        per_tgl_akhir = Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")

        frRpt.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = _
         "{Tdetail_Transaksi.tanggal_transaksi} >= DateTime(" & Format(per_tgl_awal, "yyyy") & _
        "," & Format(per_tgl_awal, "MM") & "," & Format(per_tgl_awal, "dd") & _
         ",0,0,0)AND{Tdetail_Transaksi.tanggal_transaksi}<=DateTime(" &   Format(per_tgl_akhir, "yyyy") & _
         "," & Format(per_tgl_akhir, "MM") & "," & Format(per_tgl_akhir, "dd") & ",0,0,0)"

frRpt.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `16/11/2013` is not valid . Your server setting take it as 'mm,dd,yyyy' and there is no month of 16 .
Use this code to convert this to date.

```
select CONVERT(date,'16/11/2013',103)
```

[image]

[Source](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx)

Comment: okay then thank you, now is working i use below code, the problem is on my project, after i rebuild the program is running, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

See what the DateTimePicker's date format is. Could be you need `per_tgl_awal = Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")`

EDIT: Try this instead:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "d-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss";
per_tgl_awal = DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat;
```

Comment: Hi @campagno_1, i try so suggestion, but i receive error message "date-time is required here", please help

Comment: See revision to my answer